# How to split XML String?

Tags: java, xml, split

I have this xml node. I want to split the coordinate to latitude and longitude using java.

```
<MAP>1234:3.12345,119.12345</MAP>
```

I want to split the coordinate or at least can get the coordinate with this format (lat,long). Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with regex ?

```
final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<MAP>((.*):(.*),(.*))</MAP>", Pattern.DOTALL); 
final Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(whatyouwanttoparselatlongwiththeaboveformat); 
if (matcher.find()) { 
     System.out.print(matcher.group(2) + " : (lat,lon) = ");
     float latitude = Float.valueOf(matcher.group(3));
     float longitude = Float.valueOf(matcher.group(4));
     System.out.println(latitude + "," + longitude);
}
```

Then you can deal with latitude and longitude as you wish.

Comment: Note that you probably want to get the contents of the node with an XML parser and then apply the regex to that. XML, [like HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), generally cannot be parsed with regex. But it might be fine, depending on the details of your use case.

Comment: thanks for the replies. i just have the answer. im using this code String st = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
                        String str[] = st.split(":", 2);
                        String latlong;
                        latlong = str[1];
                        out.println(latlong);